# How can I read till EOF in C#, without counting the Enter key?

Tags: c#

I've recently started learning C# after C and I've been trying to write a simple program that reads Celsius values till EOF and converts them to Fahrenheit, but my learning platform dosen't accept my code due to some kind of runtime error. When I press the Enter key in the console it gives me the error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
>   ...

for the `Convert.ToDouble` command line.
How can I fix this problem?

```
while (true)
{
    string celsius = Console.ReadLine();    

    if (celsius == null)    
        break;    

    float convcel = (float)Convert.ToDouble(celsius);    

    float fahren = (float)(1.8 * convcel) + 32;    

    Console.WriteLine(fahren);
}
```

Comment: Try `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(celsius))` (or even `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(celsius)`) instead of `if(celsius == null)`

Comment: `(float)Convert.ToDouble(...` why not just `Convert.ToSingle(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
while (true)
{
      string celsius = Console.ReadLine();    

      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(celsius))    
            break;    

       if(float.TryParse(celsius, out float convcel))    
       {
           float fahren = (float)(1.8 * convcel) + 32;    

           Console.WriteLine(fahren);    
       }
    }
```

TryParse will return `true` only if its able to convert string to `float` and assign converted value to `convcel`.

And yes as suggested in comments I have updated the if condition.

Comment: While this will prevent the error, you might never leave the `while` loop (as you won't hit the `break` part)

Comment: and I updated it again, as `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` already returns a `bool` ;)